# How to easily "Show Layout bounds" for Android debugging?

Tags: android, debugging

I want to watch the layout of App without boring tap and tap.

---

I tried `adb shell setprop debug.layout true` but **didn't work** unless reboot or open setting.
This may caused by setting haven't update.

I tried to writing a little App with code `SystemProperties.set("debug.layout", "true")` , no use too.
Maybe the app's authority…

---

Sorry for my poor English and appreciation for help :p

Answer (score 33):

This works for me:

```
adb shell setprop debug.layout true
adb shell service call activity 1599295570
```

After we have enabled Show layout bounds using `adb shell setprop debug.layout true`, we have to poke the SystemProperties to see the changes
as [Show layout bounds QS Tiles](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/f9390ce1fb932c7df6f8eace37893c5e1f0eeebd/src/com/android/settings/qstile/DevelopmentTiles.java) does:

```
@Override
public void onClick() {
    setIsEnabled(getQsTile().getState() == Tile.STATE_INACTIVE);
    new DevelopmentSettings.SystemPropPoker().execute(); // Settings app magic
    refresh();
}
```

Here's [the original method from AOSP source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/f8ad32823c5709348a5fb9618166b07394e88d99/src/com/android/settings/development/DevelopmentSettings.java):

```
public static class SystemPropPoker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String[] services = ServiceManager.listServices();
        for (String service : services) {
            IBinder obj = ServiceManager.checkService(service);
            if (obj != null) {
                Parcel data = Parcel.obtain();
                try {
                    obj.transact(IBinder.SYSPROPS_TRANSACTION, data, null, 0);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Someone wrote a bad service '" + service
                            + "' that doesn't like to be poked: " + e);
                }
                data.recycle();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The number `1599295570` is called `SYSPROPS_TRANSACTION`

Reference: https://github.com/dhelleberg/android-scripts/blob/master/src/devtools.groovy

*UPDATED: I created this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.simonpham.devtiles) to add many developer toggle to the quick settings for Android 7.0+*

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: `SYSPROPS_TRANSACTION    = B_PACK_CHARS('_', 'S', 'P', 'R')` via. IBinder.h     
     1599295570 (0x5f535052), is a combination of four ASCII chars ('_', 'S', 'P', 'R').

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tiiime/8419d9a54a53cca0e8ffdc57bf79ff48

script toogle layout bound

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to start the settings app. Just exit your app, set the property, and start your app.

```
adb shell am force-stop com.company.appname ; adb shell setprop debug.layout true ; adb shell monkey -p com.company.appname -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

Answer (score 10):

I found a DevelopQuickSetting tool can easily make this.
https://github.com/kyze8439690/DevelopQuickSetting

and the core code translate to adb shel is:

```
adb shell setprop debug.layout true
adb shell service check SurfaceFlinger
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my [fish shell](https://gist.github.com/shalva97/2f4d7bd5e17c9b7601b6dbba0335a7ff) function that will also help you to choose from multiple devices with fzf. save it in ~/.config/fish.functions/ and use it like this:

[image]

and if you have more than one device it will prompt to select one with fzf

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This tool works fine. 
You need to install groovy before launch this program.

https://github.com/dhelleberg/android-scripts

Comment: Awesome, needs some PR's to make it cover more ground.  However it handles the original query and much cleaner!

brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhelleberg/android-scripts/master/androidscripts.rb

Then type devtools