# Settings.Global.putInt() do not work immediately

Tags: android, application-settings, appsettings, android-windowmanager, android-settings

I development an app and convert it to system app. In this app I want to change three global variable: `ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE`,`WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE` and `TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE`. But after I modify the valuein through my app , I have to enter the settings(which is system app develop by google) app again to let the modify work, or the modify will not work.
Here is my code :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />

<!--system app-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

I modify the value in MainActivity when a Switch is checked

```
 public void changeAnimationSettings(boolean isChecked) {

    int result1 = isChecked ? 0 : 1;
    Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, result1);
    Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, result1);
    Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE, result1);

    Log.i(TAG, "---->>ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE: " + Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE));
    Log.i(TAG, "---->>WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE: " + Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE));
    Log.i(TAG, "---->>TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE " + Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE));
}
```

and the log show the code has modify the value successful.

Comment: I guess the the settings app can refresh the modify, but my app can not.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this happens? Or how to get the settings to update in the settings screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use this "Settings app magic" ([original taken from AOSP source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/nougat-release/src/com/android/settings/qstile/DevelopmentTiles.java)) to see the change immediately:

```
SystemPropPoker().execute()
```

Also add this class

```
class SystemPropPoker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private static final String TAG = SystemPropPoker.class.getName();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(@NonNull Void... params) {
    String[] services;
    try {
        Class serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        Method listServicesMethod = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("listServices");
        services = (String[]) listServicesMethod.invoke(null);
        for (String service : services) {
            Method checkServiceMethod = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("checkService", String.class);
            IBinder obj = (IBinder) checkServiceMethod.invoke(null, service);
            if (obj != null) {
                Parcel data = Parcel.obtain();
                final int SYSPROPS_TRANSACTION = ('_'<<24)|('S'<<16)|('P'<<8)|'R'; //copy from source code in android.os.IBinder.java
                try {
                    obj.transact(SYSPROPS_TRANSACTION, data, null, 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Someone wrote a bad service '" + service
                            + "' that doesn't like to be poked: " + e);
                }
                data.recycle();
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Reference: [How to easily "Show Layout bounds" for Android debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799848/how-to-easily-show-layout-bounds-for-android-debugging/50618460#50618460)